# after image upload process I have to rebuild my folder in Java-Spring

Tags: java, spring, image, file

I am working on Java with spring and I want to know are there any other steps need after ImageIO.write

I get the image from the user and I save it in the database there is no doubt here. But I want to keep that image in the file to display from view part. But the images are not displayed **I have to rebuild my image file for every upload process**.

The interesting thing is when I upload an image with the same name with an image that exists before in the folder it is successfully displayed.

Here is what I tried:

After some process, I write the image to my file

```
try {
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\Yusuf\\Desktop\\Yusuf\\Enes Yurdakul\\demo\\src\\main\\resources\\static\\sliders\\"+sliderModel.getImage_name()+".jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And in the view part, I basically call the images from the file

```
<div th:each="element,iter:${list}">
    <img class="mySlides" th:src="@{${'/static/sliders/'+element}}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
</div>
```

I checked al process step by step image names are correct even the image comes to the file after upload process But as ı said  I have to rebuild my image (sliders) to see that new image

Comment: you're uploading file to `src\main\resources`, which is source directory. It requires build process to make it available for your program at runtime. Use dedicated directory for that purpose.